# Как сохранить переменную в локальное хранилище localStorage чтоб при перезагрузке данные оставались на странице?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Долго сижу над простым заданием - сохранить состояние в локальную память(хранилище localStorage) чтоб при перезагрузке данные не исчезали но не получается. Я понимаю что мне нужно вытащить данные из localStorage и положить их в мою todos но typeScript выдает ошибки.. Ранее мне посоветовали делать запись в локальную память через useEffect но по-прежнему при перезагрузке все исчезает. Буду благодарен за объяснение

Код:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState<Itodo[]>([]);
  const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  localStorage.getItem("todos");
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));

  const handleEvent: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  const handlePress: React.KeyboardEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      addTodo();
    }
  };

  const addTodo = () => {
    setTodos([
      ...todos,
      {
        id: Date.now(),
        complete: false,
        title: value,
      },
    ]);
    setValue("");
  };

  const removeTodo = (id: number): void => {
    setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
  };
  const toggleTodo = (id: number): void => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id !== id) return todo;
        return {
          ...todo,
          complete: !todo.complete,
        };
      })
    );
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input
          placeholder="Enter your business"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleEvent}
          onKeyPress={handlePress}
          ref={inputRef}
        />
        <button onClick={addTodo}>Add</button>
      </div>
      <TodoList items={todos} removeTodo={removeTodo} toggleTodo={toggleTodo} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых - вы не должны делать что либо в функциональном компоненте вне функций, кроме объявления констант, функций и т.д.

Далее вам надо считывание данных перенести в эффект загрузки компонента, а сохранение в эффект изменения.

Вот пример:

```
export default function App() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState<string>("");
    const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState<Itodo[]>([]);
    const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    const handleEvent: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
    };
    const handlePress: React.KeyboardEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            addTodo();
        }
    };

    const addTodo = () => {
        setTodos([
            ...todos,
            {
                id: Date.now(),
                complete: false,
                title: value,
            },
        ]);
        setValue("");
    };

    const removeTodo = (id: number): void => {
        setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
    };
    const toggleTodo = (id: number): void => {
        setTodos(
            todos.map((todo) => {
                if (todo.id !== id) return todo;
                return {
                    ...todo,
                    complete: !todo.complete,
                };
            })
        );
    };
    // Этот эффект срабатывает только в момент установки в DOM
    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (inputRef.current) {
            inputRef.current.focus();
        }
        const data = localStorage.getItem("todos");
        // Что бы typeScript не ругался, проверим на тип
        if (typeof data === 'string') {
            setTodos(JSON.parse(data));
        }
        
        
    }, []);
    // Когда todos изменился, сохраняем
    React.useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos);
    }, [todos])

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <input
                    placeholder="Enter your business"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={handleEvent}
                    onKeyPress={handlePress}
                    ref={inputRef}
                />
                <button onClick={addTodo}>Add</button>
            </div>
            <TodoList items={todos} removeTodo={removeTodo} toggleTodo={toggleTodo} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Данный код будет работать если не добавлено `<StrictMode>`

```
root.render(<App />);
// а не так
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Если использование `<StrictMode>` необходимо для проекта, тогда считывание данных из хранилища переносим в создание стейта вот так:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState<Itodo[]>(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    // Что бы typeScript не ругался, проверим на тип
    if (typeof data === "string") {
      return JSON.parse(data);
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  });
```

и убираем его соответственно из эффекта установки компонента.

В новых версиях React в Develop режиме установка компонента происходит дважды, поэтому данные могут затираться.

Comment: Дописал ваш код но по-прежнему при перезагрузке все стирается

Comment: Эффект [todos] срабатывает? В localeStorage какие данные видите?

Comment: Да, срабатывает, все что ввожу в инпут то я и получаю в хранилище.

Comment: [{id: 1665955078911, complete: false, title: "dqdq"},…]
0
: 
{id: 1665955078911, complete: false, title: "dqdq"}
1
: 
{id: 1665955089335, complete: false, title: "dqdqd"}
2
: 
{id: 1665955105479, complete: false, title: "qddqd;q=d"}

Comment: `const data = localStorage.getItem("todos")` Вытаскивает данные?

Comment: Да, проверил в консоли

Comment: Покажите ваш `TodoList`. Если данные сохраняются и успешно достаются, то проблема кроется где то дальше

Comment: https://codepen.io/IvaLu/pen/QWrPjPP?editors=0010

Comment: @Somebody Проверьте, нет ли у вас Strict режима в index `<StrictMode>`. Я реализовал вашу логику и без данного `<StrictMode>` все работает

Comment: @Somebody Обновил ответ, добавил варианты

Comment: Да, дейтвительно работает, спасибо большое за обьяснение