# LocalStorage в React.js

Tags: reactjs

Как добавить localStorage на X и Y что бы когда в input вводил значение они сохранялись и что бы когда перемещаешь див все измененные значение в input сохранялись

Вот код на CodeSandBox [Код](https://codesandbox.io/s/moving-div-by-x-and-y-prjf2t?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {

  let positionX = localStorage.getItem("posX");
  let positionY = localStorage.getItem("posY");

  const [pressed, setPressed] = React.useState(false);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: positionX || 0, y: positionY || 0 });


  const setLocalStorageX = (value) => {
      localStorage.setItem("posX", value);
    };
    const setLocalStorageY = (value) => {
      localStorage.setItem("posY", value);
    };
  

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pressed) {
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
      window.addEventListener("mouseup", togglePressed);
    }

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", togglePressed);
    };
  }, [position, pressed]);



  const onMouseMove = (event) => {
    const x = position.x + event.movementX;
    const y = position.y + event.movementY;
    setPosition({ x, y });
  };


  const togglePressed = () => {
    setPressed((prev) => !prev);
  };


  const handleChange = (e, type) => {
    setPosition((prev) => {
      return { ...prev, [type]: e.target.valueAsNumber };
    });
    setLocalStorageX(e.target.value);
    setLocalStorageY(e.target.value);
};

  return (
    <div className="App" style={appStyle}>
      <div className="map" style={{ display: "flex" }}>
        <h1 style={h1Style}>X</h1>
        <input
          style={inputCStyle}
          className="inputC"
          type="number"
          value={position.x}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "x")}
        />
        <h1 style={h1Style}>Y</h1>
        <input
          style={inputCStyle}
          className="inputC"
          type="number"
          value={position.y}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "y")}
        />
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: "50%",
          left: "50%",
          transform: "translate(-50%,-50%)"
        }}
      >
        <div
          className={pressed ? "box_0-active" : "box-0"}
          style={{
            ...quickAndDirtyStyle,
            marginLeft: `${position.x}px`,
            marginTop: `${position.y}px`
          }}
          onClickCapture={() => setPressed(false)}
          onMouseDown={togglePressed}
        >
          <p>{pressed ? "Dragging..." : "Press to drag"}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Там где вы сохраняете значения(setPosition), там же добавьте сохранение данных в localStorage. Не очень понятна суть вопроса. Вот описание [работы с localStorage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452944/1452946#1452946), а это как [прикрутить localStarage к react компоненту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457627/1457632#1457632). Посмотрите, может найдете ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: не я так то добавляю localStorage , но он работает нормально только в input, а когда я в перемещаю див он очень быстро сьезжает куда захочет и не сохраняет данные  новые ,а сохраняет только те что были введены в ручную

Comment: У вас setPosition есть в двух местах. Сохранение надо делать и там и там. Я не вижу причин, по которой бы не сохранялись значения.

Comment: щас я изменю код и посмотрите что я сделал не так

Comment: Код изменил. Я просто до этого некогда не писал localStorage и у меня с этим проблемы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализуем сохранение значений при перетаскивании объекта:

```
  const onMouseMove = (event) => {
    const x = position.x + event.movementX;
    const y = position.y + event.movementY;
    setPosition({ x, y });
    localStorage.setItem('pos', JSON.stringify({x, y}));
  };
```

Реализуем сохранение значений при вводе значений через input

```
const handleChange = (e, type) => {
    setPosition((prev) => {
      const posNew = { ...prev, [type]: e.target.valueAsNumber }
      localStorage.setItem('pos', JSON.stringify(posNew))
      return posNew;
    });
};
```

При загрузке компонента, достаем значения из хранилища

```
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(() => {
    const pos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pos'));
    if (pos && pos.hasOwnProperty('x') && pos.hasOwnProperty('y')) {
      return pos;
    } 
    return { x: 0, y: 0}
  });
```

Comment: Спасибо, а если не трудно можешь дать какую ни-будь нормальную статью по  localStorage ?

Comment: Ну хотя бы вот [https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage](https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage). В localStorage нет ничего сложного. Строку сохранил, строку вернул.