# Потеря значения состояния при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: reactjs, api

Всем привет!
Никак не могу разобраться с проблемой, буду рада, если кто поможет)

Ситуация такая: делаю сайт с новостями по категориям (News API) и получаю список новостей по каждой категории отдельным запросом (в зависимости от выбранного фильтра). Фильтр работает, записывается категория в состояние, новости подгружаются, но при простой перезагрузке страницы значение категории сбрасывается на null.

Часть кода компонента со страницей новостей:

```
const CategoryPage = ({category}) => {
const [newsList, setNewsList] = useState([]);

const {getNewsByCategory} = useNewsService();
console.log(category);

useEffect(() => {
    getNewsByCategory(category)
        .then(setNewsList)
}, [category])}
```

Часть кода с фильтрами:

```
const NewsFilter = ({setCategory}) => {
function handleCategory(category) {
    setCategory(category)
    console.log(category);
}}
```

Состояние category хранится в корневом компоненте App:

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState(null);
```

Так выглядит страница с загруженной категорией:
[image: страница с новостями]

Comment: Просто запишите состояние категории в local storage и инициализируйте стейт оттуда же

Comment: Так у вас значение по умолчанию null. С чего вы решили, что все полученное должно сохраниться?

Comment: @SwaD начальное да, null, но я перезаписываю его в компоненте NewsFilter. То есть в App значение должно сохраняться, по идее

Comment: @MrYogurt хмм, попробую, спасибо!)

Comment: Значение сохраняется, на когда страница обновляется, все "забывается" и приложение стартует с "чистого листа". Вдруг полезно будет: [Сохранение значений в localStorage и их чтение в React](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457627/1457632#1457632)

Comment: @SwaD благодарю за помощь и за ссылку!)