# Как сделать так чтобы при клике значение сохранялось в хранилище redux

Tags: reactjs, next.js

У меня есть хранилище чтобы брать значение из `input` и отправлять его туда,  затем брать его из хранилища и использовать его в нужном месте, но не могу сделать так чтобы значение бралось только при клике Отправить и сохранялось в хранилище, значение изменяется при вводе информации(букв, цифр) или их удалении.

Таких хранилищ у меня 3, для email, для number и значение валюты, это один из них

```
class StoreEmail {
    #data = "";
    constructor(begin) {
      this.#data = begin || "";
    }
  
    setData(data) {
      this.#data = data;
    }
  
    get data() {
      return this.#data;
    }
  }
  
  const emailKey = new StoreEmail();
  
  export { emailKey };
```

Тут, на странице Payment я должен взять значение и сохранить в хранилище, а затем вставить её в `value` внутри `ipnut` на странице Success где всё это я передам в бэкенд через post.

```
import styles from './Payment.module.css'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { payKey } from "../Store";
import {amountKey} from '../StoreAmount'

const Pay = ()=>{
    
 

    const [amount, setAmount] = useState('');
  
       useEffect(() => {
           amountKey.setData(Number(amount));
       }, [amount])

    
       if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        const localData = localStorage.getItem('client')
        const [code, setCode] = useState(localData? JSON.parse(localData): console.log('ERROR'))  
        console.log(code)
      }

      
     useEffect(()=>{
       localStorage.setItem('client', JSON.stringify(payKey.data))  
     })

  

   
   
    
    return(
        <>
             <div className={styles.wrapper}>
          <div className={styles.container}>
         
          <form action="https://app.0xProcessing.com/Payment" method="post">
                          <input type="hidden" name="test" value="true" />
                          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder='Email'/>
                          <input type="number" name="amountusd"  placeholder='Количество' value={amount} onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)} />
                          <input type="text" name="currency" placeholder='Валюта' />
                          <input type="hidden" name="ShopId" value="6QsQHcQ6bX" />
                          <input type="hidden" name="ClientId" value={payKey.data} />
                          <input type="hidden" name='SuccessUrl' value={`https://next-js-web-sandy.vercel.app/success/?id=${payKey.data}`}/>
                          <input type="hidden" name='AutoReturn' value="true" />
                          <button type="submit">Send</button>
          </form>     

          </div>
         </div>
         <h1 className={styles.heading}><Link href={`/?id=${payKey.data}`}><button>Назад</button></Link></h1>
        </>
    )

}

export default Pay
```

Вот страница Success,

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'




const Success = ()=>{
     
   

    return(
        <>
          <form action="https://example.com/pay/success/" method="post">
           ///в value вставляю значение из инпута которое хранится в хранилище
                        <input type="hidden" name="tg_id" value={} placeholder=' ID'/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="amount"  placeholder='Количество' />
                        <input type="datetime-local"  name="date" placeholder='Время' />
                        <button type="submit">Send</button>
                        
           </form>     
           
        </>
    )
}

export default Success
```

Comment: Ну во первых это не redux, а собственное хранилище. Во вторых, если оно сохраняется, то разговор о каком хранилище, localStorage?

Comment: Здраствуйте, я о собственном хранилище, то есть только  при нажатии на Отправить сохранялось значение из инпута чтобы я смог передать его на странице  Success,  вызвав таким образом **import {emailKey} from '../StoreEmail'** @SwaD

Comment: Вызовите getter метод в нужом месте `emailKey.data` и все. Не понятна суть вопроса.. Если данные уже и так сохраняются, зачем их повторно где то сохранять?

Comment: ладно, даже если введённые значения куда то сохраняются то как их использовать? Мну нужно сохранить это значение в хранилище, а потом уже вызывать и вставлять их куда надо@SwaD

Comment: Где надо сохраняете `emailKey.setData(name);`, где надо вызываете и используете(вставляете) `const secret = emailKey.data` или прям в форме `<input type="hidden" name="tg_id" value={emailKey.data} placeholder=' ID'/>`.  Вопрос понятнее не стал

Comment: Я так и сделал, но я не могу понять, когда я заполняю инпут то значение меняется при вводе, то есть в хранилище будет хранится последнее введённое значение?@SwaD

Comment: В хранилище лежит то значение, которое вы сохранили методом  `setData`.

Comment: Так, с этим разобрался, осталось отправить всё это в на сервер на странице Success, знаете как? @SwaD

Comment: Что то вы рановато схватились за React, не изучив азов HTML и javascript. Если нажмете на кнопку send вся ваша форма улетит по адресу указанному в action. Почитайте про [formData](https://learn.javascript.ru/formdata), fetch или ajax запросы.

Comment: Я знаю что именно при нажатии отправляется, но я не знаю как сделать так чтобы отправлялась при переходе на страницу Success @SwaD

Comment: Почитайте про fetch или ajax запросы. Выберите более удобный для вас и возможно так окажется, что и сам компонент вам не нужен. С их помощью можно отправлять любые данные в любом месте по любому событию

Comment: Последний вопрос, как сделать так чтобы вместо string в хранилище записывалось как number?@SwaD

Comment: Передать number а не string.

Comment: Ещё проблема, я думал что не передаётся из-за того что это string, но я понял что не передаётся так как я при нажатии Отправить перехожу на другой сайт а потом возвращаюсь обратно на свой,  то есть на Success где я и должен сделать POST. Исходя из всего этого я хочу сказать что хранилище оказывается пустым когда я возвращаюсь на свой сайт, есть ли способ сделать так чтобы ничего не пропадало даже при возврате на свой сайт, могу ли я использовать  LocalStorage для этого? @SwaD

Comment: Можно! [Вот пример сохранения в localstorage в React](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457627/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%89%d0%b5-localstorage-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba/1457632#1457632)

Comment: @SwaD Сохранить получилось, но вот использовать данные из localStorage я не могу, я код обновил, можете посмотреть

Answer (score 0):

Для сохранения в localStorage и возможности чтения данных, лучше всего это организовать в классе, который выполняет фукнцию хранилища данных:

```
class StoreEmail {
  #data = "";
  constructor() {
    // При создании, читаем из стора, если ничего нет, пустая строка
    this.#data = localStorage.getItem("key") || "";
  }
  /** @param {string} data */
  setData(data) {
    this.#data = data;
    localStorage.setItem("key", data); // Сохраняем данные в стор при изменении
  }

  get data() {
    return this.#data;
  }
}
```

В нужном компоненте

```
import {emailKey} from './store.js';

// Просто подставляем данные в нужном месте
<input type="hidden" name="tg_id" value={emailKey.data} placeholder=' ID'/>
```

Или сохраняем в состоянии компонента

```
const Success = ()=>{
  const [id, setId] = useState(emailKey.data)
  render (<input type="hidden" name="tg_id" value={id} placeholder=' ID'/>)
}
```

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку ```TypeError:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')```  когда пишу  ```data``` после ```emailKey ``` , вот так  ```console.log(emailKey.data)``` . И ещё можете объяснить как туда ```id``` попадает, в хранилище @SwaD

Comment: [Почему возникает ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined or null](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1479715/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined-o)

Comment: Можете объяснить как в хранилище ```id``` попадает? @SwaD Я не могу понять, я просто беру и вызываю ```emailKey```, но что внутри data?

Comment: Почитайте [про классы](https://learn.javascript.ru/classes). Так же, возможно, вы просто забыли заимпортить `emailKey` -> `import {emailKey} from './store.js';`?

Comment: Нет, я всё ипортировал, и ещё дело не в импорте, а в наличии данных в хранилище, в консоль выводит undefined при  ```console.log(emailKey)```   ,  а если писать  ```console.log(emailKey.data)``` выдаёт ошибку. И ещё если приписать к хранилищу ```const payKey = new StoreEmail();```
 ```export { emailKey}```  то говорит что localStorage  нету. Меня тревожит одна вещь, как сохранить ``` query.id``` в  localStorage. @SwaD

Comment: @Jalil Если `console.log(emailKey)` это `undefined`, то это говорит о том, что **emailKey** не импортировано. **emailKey** как минимум должен быть `{}`. У вас должна быть строка строка вида `import {emailKey} from './store.js';` где  **'./store.js'** - имя файла, **emailKey** имя импортируемой переменной и оно же должно совпадать с именем экспортируемой переменной файла **'./store.js'**