# Больше не показывать компонент после нажатия на кнопку React / даже после обновления

Tags: reactjs, localstorage

Как сделать в Реакт так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в компоненте Notification - он больше не показывался даже при обновлении страницы?

```
 {!notificationHidden &&
     (
         <Notification
             onClose={handleCalculationNotificationClose}
         >
             <Button onClick={handleCalculationNotificationClose}>
             ОК!
             </Button>
         </Notification>
     )
}
```

.

```
const [notificationHidden, setNotificationHidden] = useState(false);
const handleCalculationNotificationClose = () => {
    setNotificationHidden(true);
};
```

Comment: Допустим, положить значение в localStorage. Вот тут показывал, как [подтянуть значение из locaStorage при создании компонента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457627/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%89%d0%b5-localstorage-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba/1457632#1457632)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы приложение проверяло значение при запуске, можно использовать **localStorage**.

В вашем примере, желаемого поведения можно достичь, изменив код следующим образом

```
const [notificationHidden, setNotificationHidden] = useState(!!localStorage.getItem('notification'));
const handleCalculationNotificationClose = () => {
    setNotificationHidden(true);
    localStorage.setItem('notification', '1');
};
```

При создании компонента, будет проверяться значение в хранилище и преобразовываться к типу `boolean`. Если что то есть, будет `true`, ничего нет, будет `false`.

При срабатывании функции `handleCalculationNotificationClose` в `localStorage` будет записано значение, которое при преобразовании к **bololean** вернет `true`, что предотвратит рендер компонента `Notification`.

Comment: SwaD , огромное спасибо!! мне очень это помогло :) который раз выручаете!